# How to index from a System.Type

Tags: c#, list, type-conversion, system.type

Let say I have a function that takes in an anonymous type. If the type that is passed in is in fact a list. Then when I try to obtain the fields within it becomes invalid. So now I check if it is an array, and if it is an array, I will get the element type first before getting the fields. But now I'm stuck, I cant find anyway to index each element inside this list. Below is an extract of the function. Any suggestions?

```
public static List<Variance> DetailedCompare<T>(T val1, T val2)
{
    List<Variance> variances = new List<Variance>();
    FieldInfo[] fi;

    if(!val1.GetType().IsArray)
        fi= val1.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                      BindingFlags.Static |
                                      BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                      BindingFlags.Public);
    else
        fi = val1.GetType().GetElementType().GetFields();

    foreach (FieldInfo f in fi)
    {
        Variance v = new Variance();
        v.Prop = f.Name;
        v.valA = f.GetValue(val1);
        v.valB = f.GetValue(val2);
        if (!v.valA.Equals(v.valB))
        {
            DetailedCompare(v.valA, v.valB);
            variances.Add(v);
        }
    }
    return variances;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two ArrayLists one for each argument, if the type is list, populate ArrayLists with elements of that list, and if type is not a list, populate ArrayLists with individual items. Then iterate over ArrayLists for comparison,(you can modify comparison method as required, e.g. one list may have more items than other)

```
    public static List<Variance> DetailedCompare<T>(T val1, T val2)
    {
        List<Variance> variances = new List<Variance>();
        FieldInfo[] fi;
        ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
        if (!val1.GetType().IsArray)
        {
            fi = val1.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                          BindingFlags.Static |
                                          BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                          BindingFlags.Public);
            list1.Add(val1);
            list2.Add(val2);
        }
        else
        {
            fi = val1.GetType().GetElementType().GetFields();
            list1.AddRange(val1 as ICollection);
            list2.AddRange(val2 as ICollection);
        }

        IEnumerator en1 = list1.GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator en2 = list2.GetEnumerator();
        while (en1.MoveNext() && en2.MoveNext())
        {
            foreach (FieldInfo f in fi)
            {
                Variance v = new Variance();
                v.Prop = f.Name;
                v.valA = f.GetValue(en1.Current);
                v.valB = f.GetValue(en2.Current);
                if (!v.valA.Equals(v.valB))
                {
                    DetailedCompare(v.valA, v.valB);
                    variances.Add(v);
                }
            }
        }

        return variances;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. you are a champ. But unfortunately, im still a long way from completing the task. There are still a lot of unexpected issues..